# public_html folder replaced with public_ftp in cPanel

Tags: wordpress, ftp, backup, cpanel, public-html

I created an ftp account for a user to access the public_html folder and used filezilla to login in and double check to make sure it took me to the right directory which it did not. I went back to double check the path and found that the public_html folder is gone and is replaced with public_ftp. Obviously there is no site live now since the entire folder is gone.

I know I did not delete anything with %100 certainty and aside from loggin in with filezilla no other action was taken on the ftp part of things. I called hostgator and they say they cannot find the folder anywhere. I wonder if hostgator support had done something inadvertently that caused this.

Has anyone gone through this or knows where I could look to find the folder. The whole thing does not make any sense to me, how could it be gone when I know nothing was deleted. I never gave access to the site to anyone.

It is a wordpress site if that has any significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete an FTP account you can choose to delete it's home folder. If you delete an FTP account that has public_html as its home folder that would mean you deleted the whole site. This may not be exactly what happened in your case but if not that, something similar.

public_ftp is typically used for anonymous users, so the fact that you are ending up there indicates there is something wrong with the permissions on the FTP account you created.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense considering what happened with me. I just learned something new and  very important. Thank you!!